# Customize serialization of a list of JAXB objects to JSON?

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jsonp, jaxb2

I am planning to serialize list of JAXB objects to JSON response. Currently below is the format I am getting. In the below response I am seeing one more object in between is "systemInfoList" which actually is showing the array. Instead I want the dependent_systems_infos should directly show array []. Also if there is a single system info response also still it should should show in the array format. I am using the Jackson parser, cxf.

Format currently I am getting:

```
{
    "dependent_systems_infos":{
        "systemInfoList":[
            {
            "system_name":"PZ_Service",
            "system_type":"Internal",
            "service_infos":[
               {
                  "service_name":"getPZAttributes",
                  "status":"DOWN",
                  "response_time_ms":50
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "system_name":"OMS",
            "system_type":"External",
            "service_infos":[
               {
                  "service_name":"CreateOrder",
                  "status":"UP",
                  "response_time_ms":2000
               },
               {
                  "service_name":"CancelOrder",
                  "status":"UP",
                  "response_time_ms":500
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Format I need:

```
{
  dependent_system_infos : [ 
      {
        system_name : 'OMS'
        system_type: 'External'
        services_infos: [ 
                  {
                  service_name : 'CreateOrder'
                      status : 'UP'
                  response_time_ms : 2000
               },
           {
              service_name : 'CancelOrder'
                      status : 'UP'
                  response_time_ms : 2000
           }
         ]
      },
      {
        system_name : 'PZ_Service'
        system_type: 'Internal'
        services_infos: [ 
                  {
                  service_name : 'getPZAttributes'
                      status : 'UP'
                  response_time_ms : 2000
               }
         ]
      }
  ]
}
```

JAXB classes I wrote:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "dependent_systems_infos")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ItineraryStatusResponse {

    private List<SystemInfo> systemInfoList;

    @XmlList
    public List<SystemInfo> getSystemInfoList() {
        return systemInfoList;
    }

    public void setSystemInfoList(List<SystemInfo> systemInfoList) {
        this.systemInfoList = systemInfoList;
    }

}

@XmlType(propOrder = {
        "systemName",
        "systemType",
        "serviceInfoList"
})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SystemInfo {

    @XmlElement(name = "system_name", required = true)
    protected SystemName systemName;

    @XmlElement(name = "system_type", required = true)
    protected SystemType systemType;

    @XmlElement(name = "service_infos", required = true)
    protected List<ServiceInfo> serviceInfoList;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know how you're generating the output, but the main issue is that you are serializing a root object that *contains* a list when you really only want to serialize the list itself. What would you expect the outputted list to look like if `ItineraryStatusResponse` had other fields in it?

You can remove the `@XmlRootElement` annotation and mark the list as an element named "dependent_systems_infos":

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public static class ItineraryStatusResponse {

  private List<SystemInfo> systemInfoList;

  @XmlElement(name = "dependent_systems_infos", required = true)
  public List<SystemInfo> getSystemInfoList() {
    return systemInfoList;
  }

  public void setSystemInfoList(List<SystemInfo> systemInfoList) {
    this.systemInfoList = systemInfoList;
  }
}
```

If you are doing the serialization yourself, another approach would be to drop the `ItineraryStatusResponse` object entirely (since it's just a wrapper around the list), and then serialize the list itself with `SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE = true` and a root name you provide:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);

AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(TypeFactory.defaultInstance());
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);

ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().withRootName("dependent_systems_infos");
System.out.println(writer.writeValueAsString(systemInfoList));
```

Both of these approaches provide the desired output in my testing with Jackson 2.2.